# I'm trying to preg_match a word, beginning with an @, not contained in sqaure brackets

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-replace-callback

That is to say, alice should be matched, but bob shouldn't in the following

```
Hello @alice and [@bob](...)
```

I can match the names themselves with the following simple regex: `/\@([\w]+)/`.

Does anyone know how to make the regex not match bob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group index 1 contains the characters you want.

Use a negative looahead.

```
@(?![^\[\]]*])(\w+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wG0yN9/4)

**OR**

Through alteration,

```
\[.*?\]|@(\w+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wG0yN9/5)

**OR**

Through PCRE verb [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex)

```
\[.*?\](*SKIP)(*F)|@(\w+)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wG0yN9/3)

Comment: If I understand the last line, the regex is matching anything inside `[]`s and essentially getting rid of it, then we matching the rest of the string for words starting with `@`.